# Removing duplicates over two columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Apologies if this has been asked before: there are numerous 'remove duplicates in Excel' questions, but I can't seem to find one that matches my exact problem.

I have two columns of customer e-mail addresses in Excel - one is a national list of about 8000, the other is localised, about 500. I'd like to remove the localised entries from the national list to avoid spamming the local recipients. How can I do this quickly?

(I am using the latest version of Excel)

Comment: -1 because you apologize in advance if it's a duplicate, but you couldn't find something that *fit exactly*, yet you didn't show us what you tried and how it didn't work for you. It's always better to show that you've tried something and what about it didn't work, then we can help you modify it or try a new way, as long as you've shown you've put forth effort to solve it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm assuming it removes duplicates sequentially: copy the 8000 below the 500 and then use the remove duplicates function for that single column. Copy from 501 and forward and you should have what you need.

(please test the initial assumption first)

Answer (score 2):

Using the built-in function should work.

1. Select both columns and choose `Remove duplicates`.
2. On the `Remove duplicates` window uncheck the first column.
3. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and it should remove the duplicates from the
   shorter list from the longer one.

[image]

*Note: leaving both columns checked will result on no duplicates being found.*

Answer (score 2):

Your specific use case has a lightning-fast solution out in the wide fields beyond the excel gates. Open Venny : https://bioinfogp.cnb.csic.es/tools/venny/ . Copy-paste both your columns to two boxes. Click the appropriate part of the Venn diagram, and the list you need will be in the output. Copy-paste the output list back into your excel. Done.

[image: Venny]

Note: Venny is a client-side javascript. All the operations happen in your browser - no third party involved. You can Ctrl+S save it to your machine and open it when offline and it'll run.